# What are the common phrases in sports when you win the score?

Tags: expressions, word-requests, learning

Sportsmen use some phrases to encourage themselves during the game.

So what do Chinese sportsmen usually say when they win the score?

For example, in [this video](http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XODc4NTQ5MjQ=.html?from=y1.2-1-98.3.1-1.1-1-1-0-0) at 5:40, Ma Lin cried something like: "chu!... fa!"

Sometimes I hear 'dui' which I suppose most likely corresponds to "对！", is it also used to encourage themselves?

Comment: "chu!... fa!" is just a personal habit to encourage himself and keep active, especially for a sportsman.

Comment: @WangYudong could you please provide some common examples for self encouragement and what characters could "chu” and "fa" be?

Comment: win the score？ unfamiliar phrase， using iciba －＞
get／make the highest score，得分最高，win 。。。赢得最高分，win the scoring title 获得得分王的称号

Comment: @S.Rhee no, not the phrase "win the score" I need self motivating shout. Like "Yeah!", "Did it!", "Awesome!"

Comment: comments may focus on peripheral issues 评论可以重点次要问题，反正至于网球而言win the game比win the score似乎还要常见

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either saying `加油` or `加油加油` in a faster speed is a way to express the encouragement to oneself or the others. Also `哈（hà）`, `耶（ye, Enligh word Yeah）`, `呵（hè）` can express the excitement when you win the score.

Actually, "chu" and "fa" are just sound and no specific Chinese characters for the meaning you want.

Comment: As I see, 加油 is not to say to yourself when doing sports, am I right? Is it just said by people who came to see the sport competition?

Comment: @IvanGerasimenkoi `Come on` has the same meaning as `加油` when to cheer up. Do you think `Come on` can't be said to oneself? Of course, in Chinsese, `加油` can be said to oneself.